# Implementing ls -t option in C

Tags: c, linux

I have to implement ls -a, ls, -t in C. I successfully implemented ls -a. But I could not handle -t option. Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void opt_a(char* path)
{
  DIR* dp = opendir(path);
  struct dirent* dirp;
  while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
  {
    printf("%s  ", dirp->d_name);
  }
  printf("\n");
  closedir(dp);
}
void print_opt(int ac, char** av)
{
  if (strcmp(av[1], "-a") == 0)
  {
    if (ac == 2)
    {
      opt_a(".");
    }
    else
    {
        opt_a(av[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't come up with -t option. Hope you guys help me find out =)

Comment: Where's the code you have so far for `-t`?

Comment: @TomKarzes I didn't add it to the code because I'm sure that my -t part doesn't correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, push all files (file_name and date) to a linked list:

```
struct linked_list_t {
    char *file_name;
    time_t date; // Get the last modification date by using stat() -> st_mtim
    struct linked_list_t *next;
};
```

Then, loop over your linked list while it's not empty; each loop you will search for file with the lowest modification date, print this file and remove the node.

Example:

```
linked_list_t *head; // head of the linked_list, contains all dates
linked_list_t *node;
linked_list_t *min_date_node;

while (head) { // loop while linked_list is not empty
    node = head;
    min_date_node = node;

    while (node) { // loop and check for the lowest date
        if (node->date < min_date_node->date)
            min_date_node = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("%s\n", min_date_node->file_name);
    removeNode(head, min_date_node); // remove min_date_node from main linked_list
}
```

ref: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

Comment: how to loop over linked list by the lowest?

Comment: why not vector ? (dynamic array) ? why we need to pay for extra memory for the pointers between the nodes? i can do this in vector, insert sorted!

Comment: I pushed all files to a linked list but how I push dates to a linked list?

Comment: Same way you did with the file_name. To get the date use "stat(file_name, &stat_struct) " and "date = stat_struct.st_mtim"

Comment: If using linked_list is too difficult for you, simply use an array of structures containing (file_name, file_date and an int used/not used). You can do this if you know how many files are going to be printed. If so, simply loop over your array using "for" loop and set the int "used" to 1 when you print the file (it replaces the removeNode() function).